# Redirect Cron Stderr and Stdout to A Log File With a Timestamp

Tags: bash, cron, io-redirection, timestamps, file-descriptors

I'm trying to get stdout and stderr to make it to my log file for a cron process. Currently, stdout makes it as intended, but stderr does not. My timestamps are creating the issue. If I remove the pipe `ts` part, both stdout and stderr to make it to the log file, but the lines don't have the nice timestamps which I need.

Bash command:

```bsh
node index.js | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' >> $(date --utc +\%Y-\%m-\%d).log 2>&1
```

Node JS script:

```js
console.log('log');
console.error('error');
```

What my log file looks like:

```
[2020-04-15 16:26:10] log
```

What I want my log file to look like:
(timestamps should reflect the exact time when each line logs)

```
[2020-04-15 16:26:10] log
[2020-04-15 16:26:11] error
```

Currently the stderr gets logged on the command line instead of making it into the dated log file, which I need. I need it to:

- append to the log file, not overwrite
- append async-ly so I can `tail -f` and see live logging while the script is still running
- every line should have a prepended timestamp `[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]` at the actual time that line gets logged
- log files should be named by the current day (but it's not necessary)

I've gotten each of these to work with the above bash command with the exception of stderr... so close! Does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: Your stderr-to-stdout redirection `2>&1` likely needs to go after the `node index.js` command

Comment: It appears that you've nailed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) for your comment above. Here is the now working bash line:

```bsh
node index.js 2>&1 | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' >> $(date --utc +\%Y-\%m-\%d).log
```